# UIImageView in UIScrollView visibly going to top left corner before repositioning in center

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I need to be able to zoom out an image and then the image should be positioned in the center of the screen. This is my `-viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.scrollView setDelegate:self];

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0014.jpg"];
    [_imageView setImage:img];

    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

    if (self.imageView.bounds.size.width < img.size.width || self.imageView.bounds.size.height < img.size.height)
    {
        self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    }

    _scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;
    _scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.1;
    _scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

I have implemented `-viewForZoomingInScrollView:` to return `_imageView.Zooming` in and out works fine at this point. Then I am trying to take care of repositioning after zooming out. I have used `- (void)centerScrollViewContents` from http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content#comments . As per the example there I tried to use it in - (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self centerScrollViewContents];
}
```

But it did not work as expected and the image view was going to the top left corner. If I implement `-(void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(CGFloat)scale` though and if I disable Bounces Zoom of the Scroll view from the Attributes Inspector it works as I want and the image view gets centered:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(CGFloat)scale
{
    [self centerScrollViewContents];
}
```

But there is one issue. It is quite visible that before being centered the image view is going to the top left corner and it does not look well. Any ideas how to  make it stop sending it to the top left corner before positioning it at the center? Also sometimes the positioning in center does not work and it just stays at the top left corner.

Comment: If you are just trying to create a zoomable image view (in a scroll view) check out this project - https://github.com/StuartMorris0/SPMZoomableUIImageView

Comment: When the orientation is being changed in this project the same issue appears - the image is very visibly dragged to the left before being centered. Any idea how to avoid this?

Comment: Just change the orientation method slightly. I imagine there is no direct approach around this. I would suggest to hide the view and show again when it is centered (if it is hidden). Further to that, you could use some animation, hide it, then set the layer alpha to 0, show it then animate its alpha back to 1 to fade it back in. ?

Comment: Good suggestions, thank you. What helped me workaround the issue easily was to adjust resizing with springs and struts instead of using constraints. I also followed this tutorial to achieve the needed functionality  - http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2012/07/07/tutorial-all-about-images-part-2-panning-zooming-with-uiscrollview/ . Now I am struggling to make the image fit the screen size when it is bigger but this issue is different than the one I have asked.

Comment: You should post your code and accept you're own answer so others can find this in the future. Thanks